# Test method is overspecified

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this `before` function in my test:

```
before((done) => {
        const cognito = new Cognito();
        return cognito.authUser(
          'john@doe.com',
          'password',
        )
      .then((res) => {
        AuthToken += res.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  });
```

It throws this error:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

I thought this may have been the fix:

```
before((done) => {
        const cognito = new Cognito();
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          cognito.authUser(
            'john@doe.com',
            'password',
          )
        })
      .then((res) => {
        AuthToken += res.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        done(err);
      });
  });
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error explains a little bit.

You can't use both callback and a return.

You have 2 options:

> callback (the `done` parameter)

```
before((done) => {
    const cognito = new Cognito();
    cognito.authUser(
        'john@doe.com',
        'password',
    )
    .then((res) => {
        AuthToken += res.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
        done();
    })
    .catch((err) => done(err));
});
```

or

> Return promise

```
before(() => {
    const cognito = new Cognito();
    return cognito.authUser(
        'john@doe.com',
        'password',
    )
    .then((res) => {
        AuthToken += res.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
    })
});
```